# Maven Surefire does not rerun failed testng test, what's wrong with my configurations?

Tags: maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I am new to surefire plugin, and trying to setup to rerun flaky test.

My configuration is as following:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <rerunFailingTestsCount>1</rerunFailingTestsCount>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And the command I used is:

```
mvn clean test -DsuiteXmlFile=testNG.xml -Dsurefire.rerunFailingTestsCount=2
```

I got:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 11.12 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite

[ERROR] ieTest1(com.mycompany.testcases.Sample.independentTest)  Time elapsed: 3.839 s  <<< FAILURE!

java.lang.AssertionError: expected [true] but found [false]
```

However I could see the /target/surefire-reports generated, but no rerun. Anybody could help figure out why the rerun is not firing?

Comment: If your test really flaky fix them...that's the only solution...not repeating them...

Comment: I do not own the tests. I am from infrastructure team who is supporting the automation running.

Comment: Than you should contact the dev people and let the fix them...

Comment: check `target/surefire-reports` there is any out put?

Comment: Yes, I got surefire reports.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#rerunFailingTestsCount , rerunFailingTestsCount only works with JUnit 4+ providers and JUnit 5+ providers since 3.0.0-M4, not with TestNG.

I'm investigating this problem too, and the most complete explanation so far seems to be there: https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/retry-failed-tests-testng/

Comment: TestNG is in our plan.

Answer (score 2):

The feature "re-run" **is supported since of 3.0.0-M4**, see the [Feature Matrix](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/featurematrix.html).

For more details see these Jiras:

[Support @ParameterizedTest for JUnit 5 test reruns](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1711)

[Rerun Failing Tests with JUnit 5](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1584)

[Surefire / Failsafe rerun failed tests functionality fails with JUnit 5 if using @DisplayName](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1701)

Don't use forkCount=0. It is mostly useless in non-trivial projects.

Cheers
Tibor17

Comment: Regarding the @DisplayName you may want to enable them in fine grained level of configuration, see https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html#Surefire_Extensions_and_Reports_Configuration_for_.40DisplayName